# JSON PHP using API pointers

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I'm trying to learn JSON and PHP using API.

My problem is that I can't get out the data of example Array 0, the output as can seen at bottom if you visit the link, just Array googled as mutch as I can but kinda new on the json array.

```
$json_data=json_decode($json_array,true);
print_r($json_data);
echo "<br>";
echo $json_data['total'],"<br>";
echo $json_data['skipped'],"<br>";
echo $json_data['count'],"<br>";
echo $json_data['0'],['name'],"<br>";
```

Comment: You want the JSON version of the link you posted?

Comment: want to be able to sort the data so i can structure it  as for now i only get the total skipped count data and not the data within 

[0] => Array ( [id] => uvklujebkpyfd57
                      [name] => somename

Comment: For better understanding in future try to see output like `echo <pre> ; print_r($json_date) ; echo </pre> ;` and read about [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop how to access array in it

Comment: Thanks Gaurav that made it much simpler :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, I think I see what you want to do. You're trying to access the second level of your array incorrectly. You don't put anything between the two bracket sets. You also don't need to put the `0` in quotes, as it is not a string. I think you want this:

```
$json_data=json_decode($json_array,true);
print_r($json_data);
echo "<br>";
echo $json_data['total'],"<br>";
echo $json_data['skipped'],"<br>";
echo $json_data['count'],"<br>";
echo $json_data[0]['name'],"<br>"; // Line changed, removed comma and quotes.
```

**EDIT:** Note that the `[0]['name']` is inside the `hits` value, so you'll probably want this instead:

```
echo $json_data['hits'][0]['name'];
```

Comment: I've actually tried that now when i changed the code it's just showing blank at bottom of the page, it's truly weird because i tried most of the stuff I've read trough on guides how to do this.

Comment: so if you do `echo $json_data['hits'][0]['name'];` it is not outputting anything? Make sure it's set by doing `if(isset($json_data['hits'][0]['name']) echo "It is set.";` If it is not set it should output nothing again. You can try the opposite by putting an `!` before `isset`

Comment: Bugfroggy thanks! now it works when adding hits? can you collaborate why that seems to worked? becouse the Array is named hits then going to hits 1, 2, 3 etc?

Comment: If you look in your `print_r` output that you posted above, you can see that this is the structure of your array.

Comment: it might be easier to illustrate if you execute `echo json_encode($json_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` between HTML `<pre></pre>` tags. This will make the array easily readable.